# Linking kv language with Python code

Tags: python, kivy

Learnt in basic examples about linking of kv with python code using id as below :

Consider the code below in my.kv:

```
<MyFirstWidget>:
    # both these variables can be the same name and this doesn't lead to
# an issue with uniqueness as the id is only accessible in kv.
txt_inpt: txt_inpt
Button:
    id: f_but
TextInput:
    id: txt_inpt
    text: f_but.state
    on_text: root.check_status(f_but)
```

In myapp.py:

```
class MyFirstWidget(BoxLayout):

    txt_inpt = ObjectProperty(None)

    def check_status(self, btn):
        print('button state is: {state}'.format(state=btn.state))
        print('text input text is: {txt}'.format(txt=self.txt_inpt))
```

and this code works i.e. we can access Label using txt_inpt . I am trying to do same in my code for a button but i am getting an error :

```
play_Button.text = 'hello'
```

AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute 'text'

See code below :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics import Color


gui = '''
<MenuScreen>:
    play_Button: playButton
    GridLayout:

        size_hint: .2, .2
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        rows: 1
        Button:
            id: playButton
            text: 'Play !'

'''

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    play_Button = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MenuScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #If i use below one it works
        #self.ids.playButton.text = 'hello'

    Builder.load_string(gui)
    play_Button.text = 'hello'
    pass

class MyJB(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyJB().run()
```

If i use ids.play_Button it works as intended but seems I am doing something wrong with the other way. Can someone advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    play_Button = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MenuScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #If i use below one it works
        #self.ids.playButton.text = 'hello'

    Builder.load_string(gui)
    play_Button.text = 'hello'
    pass
```

You are missing some indentation here, the `play_Button.text` line should be in the `__init__` method (and the `pass` does nothing so you can remove it). Is this a typo on SO, or in your actual code?

If it's in your actual code, it causes the given error because it's being run when the class is declared, not during instantiation of an instance of the class. That means it doesn't see the object held by the objectproperty, but just the ObjectProperty itself...which (as per the error) has no attribute 'text'.

It would also be more normal to load the kv string in your app's `build` method or even outside any classes.